# Add class to different Divs in Window vertical Scroll using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, scroll, addclass

I want to add a **Class** in different **Divs** during **Vertical Scroll** using `jQuery`. I managed to add to the first `Div class` during scroll but couldn't find the solution to others.

**Here's my jQuery Code**. It's working

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();   
    if (scroll >=200 ) {
      jQuery('.feature-box').addClass('fadeInUp animated');
    } else {
        jQuery(".feature-box").removeClass("fadeInUp animated");
    }
    removeClass('fadeInUp animated');
});
```

**And I want another class to another div during scrolling. Something like this**

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll_more = jQuery(window).scrollTop();   
    if (scroll_more >=400 ) {
      jQuery('.more-box').addClass('fadeInUp animated');
    } else {
        jQuery(".more-box").removeClass("fadeInUp animated");
    }
    removeClass('fadeInUp animated');
});
```

But it wont add Class to `more-box` class. Am I missing anything here?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: you can add like this jQuery('.feature-box,.more-box').addClass('fadeInUp animated');

Comment: that works but I want to add only when scroll to the different div positions

Comment: can you make fiddle?

Comment: Hmm, I guess but it wont display scroll since I am using different template files for divs. I think you understood my question right?

Comment: Yes. I understood. can you post some static html?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1x0109c4/

haven't added `css`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint (not tested):

```
jQuery( '.feature-box, .more-box' ).each( function() {

    var wt = jQuery( window ).scrollTop();
    var ct = jQuery( this ).offset().top;

    if( wt > ct ) {

        jQuery( this ).addClass( 'fadeInUp animated' );

    } else {

        jQuery( this ).removeClass( 'fadeInUp animated' );

    }

} );
```

Probably you should trigger a bit earlier like this:

```
wt > ( ct - 200 )
```

Comment: Actually, my sections are not nested in class, they are different `sections` with different `classes`. Can you edit your code refering to my above question? https://jsfiddle.net/1x0109c4/ my fiddle for reference.
Thanks

Comment: Seems to be pretty hacky. Just select like jQuery('.feature-box, .more-box') instead of jQuery( '.fadeInBox' ) ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want both the conditions to be checked simultaneously:-

```
if (scroll >=200 ) {
  jQuery('.feature-box').addClass('fadeInUp animated');
} else {
    jQuery(".feature-box").removeClass("fadeInUp animated");
}
if(scroll >= 400){
  jQuery('.more-box').addClass('fadeInUp animated');
} else {
    jQuery(".more-box").removeClass("fadeInUp animated");
}
removeClass('fadeInUp animated');
```

If you want only one of the conditions to be true:-

```
if(scroll >= 400){
  jQuery('.more-box').addClass('fadeInUp animated');
} 
else if(scroll >= 200){
  jQuery('.feature-box').addClass('fadeInUp animated');
}
else {
    jQuery(".more-box").removeClass("fadeInUp animated");
    jQuery(".feature-box").removeClass("fadeInUp animated");
}
removeClass('fadeInUp animated');
```

Comment: classes added with the second part. Yes , that's similar to what I need. But, Once I refresh the page and scroll down, `feature-box` keeps on adding class when I scroll to top and scroll down, but `more-box` class doesn't add another class. Actually, what I need is removing class once the scrolling is done.